# Javascript: iterate through dynamically changing dictionary

Tags: javascript, dynamic, dictionary, loops

I'm trying to iterate through a dictionary while dynamically changing its size, by adding elements in Javascript. The dictionary is initialized with 1 element.
Pseudo code should look like this:

```
dict = {1:1};
i = 0;
for key in dict{
  dict[i] = i+1;
  i++;
  if i==10{break;}
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: If you're growing your dictionary, a for-loop-iterator over the dictionary object isn't going to help you much.

Comment: I'm trying to make a dijkstra algorithm which was implemented in python: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466-dijkstras-algorithm-for-shortest-paths/ it uses a priorityDict, but also works with orderedDict(). So now i'm looking for a similar solution but in javascript

Comment: @box: Several JS implementations for Dijkstra's algorithm are already available. Are you doing this just as an exercise? Otherwise: https://bitbucket.org/wyatt/dijkstra.js/src/fb6c30a3cebd/dijkstra.js?at=default

Comment: Yes i searched for other solutions, but this one in python looked really elegant and easy to understand. Thanks for the link anyways!

Comment: The order in which a `for ... in` iterates over the elements is not defined. So if you add a new elements then the iterated would need to track all newly added or remove elements and this isn’t done due to performance reasons. This is also true for other languages that even invalidate iterations if you change the container.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary keys (object properties) shouldn't be integers, but this will grow your "dictionary" to have 10 elements (it will only add nine because it will skip when `i == 1`:

```
var dict = { 1: 1 };
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (!dict.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        dict[i] = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe i haven't described it accurately but I actually don't know if the number in the end will be 10, so it's changing constantly.